# KeyEvent for "Enter" Key doesn't work in JCEF on Mac

Tags: chromium-embedded

I'm using JCEF and extending CefBrowser_N.  The following code fails to simulate a key press in JCEF's off-screen renderer on Mac but works on Windows.

```
  KeyEvent ev = new KeyEvent(canvas_, KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, 0, 0, 0, '\r');
  sendKeyEvent(ev);
```

I've tried a bunch of things.  I've used the '\n' character.  I've also tried using KEY_PRESSED instead of KEY_TYPED.  And I've tried supplying the key code, e.g.:

```
  KeyEvent ev = new KeyEvent(canvas_, KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, 0, 0, KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, '\r');
  sendKeyEvent(ev);
```

Basically no permutation of the above ideas works on Mac.

Am I facing a bug in JCEF?  Can anyone think of something else that might work?  Is there an alternative way to simulate a key event?

Comment: I assume you mean something like "\r\n"?  Can't, though.  The constructor for KeyEvent takes a char, not a string.

Comment: Just tried `char j;          j = '\r\n';` it compiled and did not crash.

Comment: I get "Invalid character constant" in Java 1.8

Comment: I dont know if this will be of any help but: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/kevent.2.html